# exercise VII.G5 in kunen

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Recall $Fn(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ is the set of partial functions with domain contained in $\alpha$, range contained in $\beta$, size $< \! \gamma$.  How do you prove that $Fn(\aleph_\omega,2,\aleph_\omega)$ collapses $\aleph_{\omega+1}$?  I see why it collapses $\aleph_\omega$ but I don't see why it kills the successor too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's wrong!  Not again Ken!

Assume $\aleph_\omega$ is a strong limit.  Let $\lbrace p_\alpha : \alpha < \aleph_{\omega+1} \rbrace$ be a set of conditions in $\mathbb{P} = Fn(\aleph_\omega,2,\aleph_\omega)$.  Since $\aleph_{\omega+1}$ is regular, there is some $n < \omega$ such that $A = \lbrace \alpha : |p_\alpha| = \aleph_n \rbrace$ has size $\aleph_{\omega+1}$.  Let $2^{\aleph_n} = \aleph_m < \aleph_\omega$.  Take the first $\aleph_{m+1}$ many members of $A$, and call this set $B$.

Consider the set of domains $\lbrace dom(p) : p \in B \rbrace$. Since $\aleph_m^{\aleph_n} = \aleph_m$, the delta-system lemma applies, and there is a set $C \subseteq B$ of size $\aleph_{m+1}$ and a fixed set $r$ such that for all $p,q \in C$, $dom(p) \cap dom(q) = r$.  Since there are only $\aleph_m$ functions from $r$ to 2, there are $p,q \in C$ which are compatible.  Therefore, $\mathbb{P}$ has the $\aleph_{\omega+1}$ chain condition.

On the other hand, it is not hard to show that if $\aleph_\omega$ is not a strong limit, then $\mathbb{P}$ collapses $\aleph_\omega^{<\aleph_\omega}$.

It's very hard to prove something that is consistently false.

Comment: I'm too tired to follow this answer and verify its correctness, but let me just point out that my experience (with Jech) is that you learn a whole lot more from the mistakes. Mainly because you have to muster up all your knowledge to come up with a counterexample on your own, which is ten times harder than solving a problem (which often has a hint).

Comment: @Asaf, good point. However I would not want to say that it is a good thing to put a few random mistakes in books just to test the reader...

Comment: No, of course not. If were to write a textbook I'm not going to spice it up with mistakes. Although I might put a section of "find the mistake in this statement" through each chapter.